# Finding all URLs called by a browser for loading a specific URL using Safari, Chrome or Firefox Dev Edition

Tags: html5, ajax

I would like to sort all URLs of my website into two categories: static (=cacheable) and dynamic. Sadly the shop software does not have a URL structure allowing for this distinction.

So what I would like to do is calling a handful of critical addresses e.g. the home  page and analyse which URLs get called by the code loaded. I'm pretty sure that all non cacheable URLs are called by AJAX and JavaScript.

How to accomplish this using Safari, Chrome or Firefox?